# How to Search in String in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

> Input:

```
Error : -12899-ORA-12899: value too large for column "MILLER"."DAS_PAYSOURCES"."NATIONAL_INSURANCE_NUMBER" (actual: 10, maximum: 9) Record No : 11 Field : PAYROLL_NO Value :'16712'
```

Output:

```
Record No, Column Name, Issue, Maximum Allowed Length,Actual Length 
    11, NATIONAL_INSURANCE_NUMBER,Value Too Large,9,10
```

Solution

```
   DECLARE
    V_RECORD_NO  VARCHAR2(2000):='Error:-12899-ORA-12899: value too large for 
  column "MILLER"."DAS_PAYSOURCES"."NATIONAL_INSURANCE_NUMBER" 
  (actual:10,maximum:9)Record No : 11 Field : PAYROLL_NO Value :16712';
   BEGIN

    V_RECORD_NO:=SUBSTR(V_RECORD_NO,INSTR(V_RECORD_NO,'RecordNo'),9)||','||

    SUBSTR(V_RECORD_NO,INSTR(V_RECORD_NO,'PAYROLL_NO'),10)||','||

    SUBSTR(V_RECORD_NO,INSTR(V_RECORD_NO,'12899-ORA-12899'),15);

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_RECORD_NO);
   END;
```

I have used instr function for searching, but used hardcode value for searching.

How to search without hardcode value.

Comment: Please specify input value and the output require from this. Do want to substr number out of error string.

Comment: yes i think he needs to do using substr and instr

Answer (score 0):

You could use `regexp_replace()` to parse this error message:

Something like:

```
select regexp_replace(
        'Error : -12899-ORA-12899: value too large for column "MILLER"."DAS_PAYSOURCES"."NATIONAL_INSURANCE_NUMBER" (actual: 10, maximum: 9) Record No : 11 Field : PAYROLL_NO Value :16712',
        '^.*ORA-\d+: (.*) for column (\S+)\s*\(actual\s*:\s*(\d+), maximum\s*:\s*(\d+)\) Record No\s*:\s*(\d+).*$',
        '\5, \2, \1, \3, \4'
    ) parsed 
from dual
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5329f53c6f85e0e8322cc718aa75d86b)**:

```
| PARSED                                                                            |
| :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 11, "MILLER"."DAS_PAYSOURCES"."NATIONAL_INSURANCE_NUMBER", value too large, 10, 9 |
```

Comment: i need output  Record No, Column Name, Issue, Maximum Allowed Length,Actual Length 11,NATIONAL_INSURANCE_NUMBER,Value Too Large,9,10

Comment: @DINESHPATEL: please explain what is wrong in the results that this query produces.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr` to get all those values in individual colums as following:

```
with dataa (str) as
(select 'Error:-12899-ORA-12899: value too large for column "MILLER"."DAS_PAYSOURCES"."NATIONAL_INSURANCE_NUMBER" (actual:10,maximum:9)Record No : 11 Field : PAYROLL_NO Value :16712' from dual)
-- your query starts from here
select 
  regexp_substr(str,'Record No : (\d+)',1,1,null,1) as col1,
  regexp_substr(str,'".+"\.".+"\."(.+)"',1,1,null,1) as col2,
  regexp_substr(str,'ORA-\d+: (.+) "',1,1,null,1) as col3,
  regexp_substr(str,'maximum:(\d+)\)',1,1,null,1) as col4,
  regexp_substr(str,'\(actual:(\d+),',1,1,null,1) as col5
from dataa
```

[Db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c2661e09ef73ba26f9d343e9e2137b0f)

Cheers!!